# Custom function of calculating median (with strings)

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm doing an exercise from DataQuest and I am trying to find the median of a column with strings.

The column is 'TotRms AbvGrd' in the houses dataframe. An example of the column is: [4, 6, 2, 6, 4, 10 or more, etc.]

```
comparator = lambda x : int(x.split()[0]) if type(x) is str else x

def median_calc(array):
    sorted_list = sorted(array, key=comparator)
    if len(sorted_list) % 2 == 1:
        median = sorted_list[int((len(array)/2))]
        return median
    else:
        middle_indices = [int((len(sorted_list)/2)), int((len(sorted_list)/2 + 1))]
        median = sum(sorted_list[middle_indices]) / 2
        return median

median = median_calc(houses['TotRms AbvGrd'])
```

I'm having trouble on this part about finding the value of the index in the else statement. How am I supposed to look up the value given the index?

> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: You should give the full error message, explaining the exact line where it occurs. And to contain a true [mcve] your question is lacking example data.

Comment: Error is on median = sum(sorted_list[middle_indices]) / 2

Comment: Cannot reproduce with a simple dataframe for `house`. Without example data reproducing the error, this question cannot be answered and is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Since houses seems like a pandas dataframe, you could just use the built-in function `median`.

An example:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'TotRms AbvGrd': ['4', '6', '2', 7, 8, '10']})
df['TotRms AbvGrd'].median()
# 6.5
```

Comment: I know I can do it this way but I want to think about it logically through a custom function.

Comment: Ah, okay. Your problem comes from the fact that calling `sorted(array, key=comparator)` gives you a python list. In the else statement, you try to pass multiple indices at once to it, which doesn't work for a python list.